# Cannot connect to Internet in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, internet

I have 3 physical network adapters and "ip addr" receive this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:e4:35:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:a4:1a:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:a4:1a:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and when I plug in internet cable, I got a error - "activation of network connection failed".
tail -f var/log/syslog I got this:

```
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050300.8971] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 3' (4bdf56c2-e37a-39d4-a1f4-ddc769e5091f)
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050300.8973] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="4bdf56c2-e37a-39d4-a1f4-ddc769e5091f" name="Wired connection 3" pid=1154 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050300.8976] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050300.8979] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050300.8985] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050300.8995] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050300.9000] dhcp4 (enp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050300.9023] dhcp4 (enp4s0): dhclient started with pid 3388
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d76:ca03:b6f:1993.
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Registering new address record for fe80::d76:ca03:b6f:1993 on enp4s0.*.
Sep  2 17:38:20 RobotControlSystem dhclient[3388]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x9e8c266e)
Sep  2 17:38:23 RobotControlSystem dhclient[3388]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x9e8c266e)
Sep  2 17:38:28 RobotControlSystem dhclient[3388]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x9e8c266e)
Sep  2 17:38:33 RobotControlSystem dhclient[3388]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x9e8c266e)
Sep  2 17:38:40 RobotControlSystem dhclient[3388]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x9e8c266e)
Sep  2 17:38:51 RobotControlSystem ubuntu-report[936]: level=error msg="data were not delivered successfully to metrics server, retrying in 480s"
Sep  2 17:38:56 RobotControlSystem dhclient[3388]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x9e8c266e)
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <warn>  [1599050345.8559] dhcp4 (enp4s0): request timed out
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050345.8559] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050345.8722] dhcp4 (enp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3388
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050345.8722] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed timeout -> done
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050345.8727] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050345.8730] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <warn>  [1599050345.8735] device (enp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 3'
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050345.8743] device (enp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d76:ca03:b6f:1993 on enp4s0.
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d76:ca03:b6f:1993.
Sep  2 17:39:05 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Interface enp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep  2 17:42:52 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[780]: <info>  [1599050572.9419] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 3'
```

**Update 1:**
Also I can manually set Ip address, subnet mask, gateway and dns server and got this:

```
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8209] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 3' (4bdf56c2-e37a-39d4-a1f4-ddc769e5091f)
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8211] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="4bdf56c2-e37a-39d4-a1f4-ddc769e5091f" name="Wired connection 3" pid=4293 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8214] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8217] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8222] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8237] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::d76:ca03:b6f:1993.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Registering new address record for fe80::d76:ca03:b6f:1993 on enp4s0.*.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.88.207.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem avahi-daemon[779]: Registering new address record for 192.168.88.207 on enp4s0.IPv4.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem whoopsie[1555]: [19:51:03] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8278] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8288] device (enp4s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8290] device (enp4s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8291] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8386] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8388] policy: set 'Wired connection 3' (enp4s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem NetworkManager[3879]: <info>  [1599058263.8394] device (enp4s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.121' (uid=0 pid=3879 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem gsd-sharing[1290]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem gsd-sharing[1290]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem gsd-sharing[1290]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [enp4s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Sep  2 19:51:03 RobotControlSystem nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [enp4s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Sep  2 19:51:13 RobotControlSystem whoopsie[1555]: [19:51:13] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Sep  2 19:51:23 RobotControlSystem whoopsie[1555]: [19:51:23] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Sep  2 19:51:29 RobotControlSystem systemd-resolved[581]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.88.1.
Sep  2 19:51:33 RobotControlSystem whoopsie[1555]: [19:51:33] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: It looks like no DHCP server responded within 35 seconds.  Do you have a DHCP server on your network?

Comment: Yes, I have a TP-link router with enabled DHCP

Comment: Try to use another DHCP server (shared internet from my phone and configured bridge via windows PC) - got the simular problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your network interfaces are down, you can up them with "sudo ifup 'interface' up", there are a couple of other commands, if that does not work with setting them up.
You can set up static IP or DHCP lease in "50-cloud-init.yaml".
Using "sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml", then "netplan try", then "netplan apply".
Test by pinging a server, ie. "google.com".

Comment: Looks like you are righ. Command "sudo ifquery -l " receive me - "lo".
But restarting interfaces and services cannot solve my problem. 
I try this:
"sudo service networking restart";
"sudo systemctl restart networking.service";
"sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager";
"sudo nmcli networking off && nmcli networking on";
"sudo ifdown -a && ifup -a".

Comment: And I don't have file "50-cloud-init.yaml" in specified folder

Comment: And one more detail: if i set manual network parameters I can ping Ubuntu PC from my host PC.

Comment: As long as the IP you specify is not in use, and your connection to the router is good. Yes, all you're doing there is telling the router, this is my IP, and not asking for one. You can also do it through your ISP's settings, but I normally do so on the device itself, for servers.

Comment: Jacobta47, after I manually set network parameters I can pins any PC in local network, but i cannot ping Router from Ubuntu PC. Also In router connection list i succefully can see my Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Can you check your routers' connections to see if the Eth port your PC is on is active, or shutdown? If active see if you can manually set its IP, DNS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is in router settings. Security option - Access control was enabled and check router clients by Mac Adderess.